# Bicubic Interpolation Error in image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, interpolation, bicubic

I have implemented Bicubic Interpolation taking the reference of these [slides](https://ia802707.us.archive.org/23/items/Lectures_on_Image_Processing/EECE_4353_15_Resampling.pdf). Slide number 118 gives the formulation to compute the Bicubic Interpolation.

I have implemented my code in the same way keeping P(dr-m) and P(n-dc) as:

```
P_dr = 1/6*( (max(d_r-m+2,0)^3) -4*(max(d_r-m+1,0)^3) -6*(max(d_r-m,0)^3) -4*(max(d_r-m-1,0)^3));
P_dc = 1/6*( (max(n-d_c+2,0)^3) -4*(max(n-d_c+1,0)^3) -6*(max(n-d_c,0)^3) -4*(max(n-d_c-1,0)^3));
```

where the max function defines by Q(X) as defined in the slide.

But when I run the code, I get the following image:

[image: Image when the normalizing factor is 1/6].

But when I change my normalizing factor to 1/32, I get:

[image: Normalizing factor is 1/32]

My original image is this:

[image: Original Image]

Can someone point as to where I am going wrong?

The code snippet is as follows:

```
for i = 5:r_new-4
    for j = 5:c_new-4
        x = i/SF;
        y = j/SF;
        ro = round(x);
        co = round(y);
        d_r = x - ro; 
        d_c = y - co;
        temp = 0;
        for m = -1:2
            for n = -1:2
              P_r = 1/32*( (max(d_r-m+2,0)^3) - 4*(max(d_r-m+1,0)^3) - 6*(max(d_r-m,0)^3) - 4*(max(d_r-m-1,0)^3));
              P_c = 1/32*( (max(n-d_c+2,0)^3) - 4*(max(n-d_c+1,0)^3) - 6*(max(n-d_c,0)^3) - 4*(max(n-d_c-1,0)^3));
              temp = temp + I(ro+m,co+n)*P_r*P_c;
            end
        end
        I_new(i,j) = temp;
    end
end
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Can you explain the byte storage order of these images ?

Comment: I have added a snippet of my code

Comment: @YvesDaoust  any suggestions ?

Comment: Can you explain the byte storage order of these images ?

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by byte storage order?

Comment: That code probably won't work with an RGB image. Have you tried it on a monochrome image (use rgb2gray if available)? More generally, to debug something: start simple. Try it on a matrix of zeros with a single 1; try resizing it to exactly its original size. Once the simple cases make sense, try more complicated ones...

Comment: Actually, it worked, I had to just change the coefficients. -6 to +6 and it works completely fine.